# How to always refresh listview in android?

Tags: android, listview, listview-adapter

I am using `ListView` in android.

when I click the button, I need to refresh my Listview.
but it is not working.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(final String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

Button refBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.refresh);
refBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
         adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
     }
});
```

and second question.

without button click, perhaps , is it possible to always update listview?

if I change my data, update my listview.

please give advice for me

if you want more information. please comment

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the `onClick()` method try to show a tost,to test whether it shows or not.

Why don't you  initialize the view(findViewById) 、set on clilk listener in the `onCreate()` method.

Your second question,although maybe my advice is not recommend ,it works.

I have the same question before,and I tried to use `Timer` and `TimerTask`.The code will automatical run.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            update();
        }
    };

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(task, 3000, 1500);
```

Answer (score 0):

That `final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter` in your `onPostExecute` is not attached to any `ListView` (unless you're not showing the full code)

Use the `adapter` that is attached to your `ListView`, the `adapter` used in the `listview.setAdapter(adapter)`

Comment: my source In `onPostExecute` , `final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter`, `ListView` all in    and not work